# Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, node-modules

i was building an angular 2 project. And once i have changed something on my html file. For example, i want to create a drop down nav bar. And This erro keeps showing up.

**Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined**

And i have fixed it for some reason when i change the code. but when i changed again, it shows. My navbar.component.html looks like this. And the problem is the third span 'Report'. I want to create a drop down nav bar.

```
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
    alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='main-nav'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">Angular</a>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
                <span  (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'></div>
        <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' >
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Log In
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" data-toggle="dropdown">Report <!--[routerLink]="['/margin']"-->
                         </a>
                            <!--<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span>Report-->
                        <!--</a>-->
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']"><a [routerLink]="['/margin']">Margin Report</a></li>
                            <li><a>Report 1</a></li>
                            <li><a>Report 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there anyone know this issue? this was so annoying..

Comment: You need to add <link>s to your src html file, not any component templates. Also, it probably uses jquery so you'll need that.

Comment: Yeah thats one thing, but not related to the issue though